# Get value of input fields using PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside2, qdialog

I am trying to use PySide2 with the dialog buttons.

Each column on the dialogWindow has a chexbox, a button and a label.

Clicking on the button `Set Text` opens another dialog box to enter a text. I would like to get the input value of this dialog box (`just enter this`), and update the label next to the clicking button. In this case, changing the first label value `Set value` to `just enter this`, as I clicked on the first `Set text` button.

Finally, by clicking on the "Apply" button, I would like to get the values of the check boxes, and the labels (those at the end of each row with `Set value`).

Below are the dialog boxes and the code

[image: Illustration]

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QPushButton,
    QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QInputDialog, QCheckBox
)

import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent, it
    will appear as a free-floating window as we want.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def init_input_dialog(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter something:')

        if ok:
            return str(text)


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        v = QVBoxLayout()

        objets = ['label1', 'label2']

        for a in objets:
            h = QHBoxLayout()

            check_box = QCheckBox()

            labels = QLabel( a )
            button = QPushButton("Set text")
            button.pressed.connect(
                lambda val=a: self.show_new_window(val)
            )

            label_value = QLabel( "Set value", objectName=a )

            h.addWidget(check_box)
            h.addWidget(labels)
            h.addWidget(button)
            h.addWidget(label_value)

            # Add the current objet entry to the main layout
            v.addLayout(h)

        # Add buttons: Ok and Cancel
        btn_ok = QPushButton("Apply")
        btn_ok.clicked.connect(self.get_dialog_box_values)

        btn_cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        btn_cancel.clicked.connect(self.close_dialog_box())

        h = QHBoxLayout()
        h.addWidget(btn_ok)
        h.addWidget(btn_cancel)

        v.addLayout(h)

        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(v)

    def show_new_window(self, n):
        win = AnotherWindow()
        val = win.init_input_dialog()
        print(val)

        # Replace the corresponding label with this value
        # label_value.setText(str(val))

    def get_dialog_box_values(self):
        # Get state of checkboxes, and label values
        check_box_values = []
        label_values = []
        print(check_box_values)
        print(label_values)

    def close_dialog_box(self):
        # Close the dialog box
        pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am also open to any suggestions on how to achieve this in a better way.
e.g. if there is a better way to add the `Apply` and `Cancel` buttons to the main dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to references to all the widgets that you plan to interact with after they have been created and placed into a layout.  In your example and description, at a minimum, you need to be able to interact with the labels at the end of each row, and the checkbox labels, so those are the widgets you should keep a reference to.  You can do this by making them attributes of the Window class by giving them the `self` assignment.  This is an important and one of the key concepts in the world of OOP.

Once they have been assigned as attributes of the window class you can refer to them with the same `self` object within any of the instance methods for that class.

For example:

```
...
...
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        hlayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.check_box1 = QCheckBox("label1")
        self.check_box2 = QCheckBox("label2")
        button1 = QPushButton("Set text")
        button2 = QPushButton("Set text")
        self.label_value1 = QLabel("Set value")
        self.label_value2 = QLabel("Set value")
        button1.pressed.connect(lambda: self.show_new_window(self.label_value1))
        button2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.show_new_window(self.label_value2))
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.check_box1)
        hlayout2.addWidget(self.check_box2)
        hlayout1.addWidget(button1)
        hlayout2.addWidget(button2)
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.label_value1)
        hlayout2.addWidget(self.label_value2)
        # Add the current objet entry to the main layout
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout1)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout2)
        # Add buttons: Ok and Cancel
        btn_ok = QPushButton("Apply")
        btn_ok.clicked.connect(self.get_dialog_box_values)
        btn_cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        btn_cancel.clicked.connect(self.close_dialog_box)
        hlayout3 = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout3.addWidget(btn_ok)
        hlayout3.addWidget(btn_cancel)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout3)
        self.setLayout(vlayout)
    
    def show_new_window(self, label):
        win = AnotherWindow()
        val = win.init_input_dialog()
        label.setText(val)

    def get_dialog_box_values(self):
        check_box_values = [i.text() for i in [self.check_box1, self.check_box2]]
        label_values = [i.text() for i in [self.label_value1, self.label_value2]]
        print(check_box_values)
        print(label_values)

...
...
```

---

#### Used in a for loop

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.check_boxes = []
        self.labels = []
        for i in range(1,3):
            hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
            check_box = QCheckBox(f"label{i}")
            button = QPushButton("Set text")
            label_value = QLabel("Set value")
            button.pressed.connect(lambda x=i-1: self.show_new_window(self.labels[x]))
            hlayout.addWidget(check_box)
            hlayout.addWidget(button)
            hlayout.addWidget(label_value)
            self.labels.append(label_value)
            self.check_boxes.append(check_box)
            # Add the current objet entry to the main layout
            vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        # Add buttons: Ok and Cancel
        btn_ok = QPushButton("Apply")
        btn_ok.clicked.connect(self.get_dialog_box_values)
        btn_cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        btn_cancel.clicked.connect(self.close_dialog_box)
        hlayout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout2.addWidget(btn_ok)
        hlayout2.addWidget(btn_cancel)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout2)
    
    def show_new_window(self, label):
        win = AnotherWindow()
        val = win.init_input_dialog()
        label.setText(val)

    def get_dialog_box_values(self):
        check_box_values = [i.text() for i in self.check_boxes]
        label_values = [i.text() for i in self.labels]
        print(check_box_values)
        print(label_values)

    def close_dialog_box(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alexander. Could you provide an example with the for loop? The number of objects is variable.

Comment: I have tried to adapt your answer to a for loop, but it is currently updating only the last label `Set value`)

Comment: It's not working yet.

Comment: sorry try it now this time I did test it @Kyv

Comment: Thank you. It works with lambda x=i. With i-1, the previous label is being updated.

Comment: This ` [i.text() for i in self.labels]` return the text right, not the checkstates.

Comment: The `isChecked()` function did it. Thank you for your support @Alexander

Comment: Could you please explain me what is going on here `self.show_new_window(self.labels[x])`? The variable `self.list_labels` is empty but you 
 are indexing it

Comment: @kyv  that is true, because when that function will eventually be called it won't be empty anymore. You can move that line down below the `self.labels.append(...)` line if you prefer but the effect will be identical.  If you want to know the checkstate of a checkbox you should use the `checkState()` method which will return whether it is checked or not instead of just a boolean value

Comment: And the keyword arg is set to `i-1` because the `range()` loop starts at 1, and we are trying to update the label at 0 so it's `i-1`